# Angular does not send HTTP Only Cookie

Tags: node.js, angular, cookies, angular-cookies

I have a small Angular 7 Application, which stores the JWT used for authentication in a HTTP ONLY cookie. The cookie gets issued by a Node.js Server. For some reason, the cookie gets stored in the Browser, but is not sent back with HTTP requests (the cookie is not secure, so it should be sent over http).

The Node Server issues the Cookie:

```
 res.cookie('http_only' , token , { httpOnly: true ,  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15 })
```

An example request:

```
getDivisions() {return this._http.get<any>(this.divisionsUrl, {withCredentials: true});}
```

Both (Client and Server) share the same Host (on a local machine).

Any Ideas how to solve this problem?